# ant: calling antcall from <script> throws a java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: ant

In the ant 1.8.2 build system, I am having a javascript that rely on an `<antcall/>`. That causes me a `java.lang.NullPointerException` which points to antcall.

Script:

```xml
<project default="main">
    <target name="main">
        <script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[
        task = project.createTask( 'macro' );
        task.execute();
        ]]></script>
    </target>

    <macrodef name="macro">
        <sequential>
            <antcall target="antcall" />
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <target name="antcall">
        <echo>[antcall] succeed</echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

build.xml:11: java.lang.NullPointerException( #3 ... ). The stacktrace just talk about RhinoScriptEngine, not sure that is any helpful

```
at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:153)
at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:167)
at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:247)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectUtil.invoke(ReflectUtil.java:108)
at org.apache.tools.ant.util.ReflectWrapper.invoke(ReflectWrapper.java:81)
at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.evaluateScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:103)
at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.executeScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:67)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Script.execute(Script.java:52)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

My questions are:
- can someone reproduce that issue?
- Am I doing something obviously wrong?
- Any ant guru around to assist me :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a bug report in Groovy detailing a similar issue http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-1506 . The [attached patch by Andreas Sahlbach](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/attachment/23061/antcall-from-groovy-task.patch) fixed the groovy issue by assigning an owner to a newly created task.

So I have gone ahead and added:

```
task.setOwningTarget( self.getOwningTarget() );
```

That fixed the issue. I have put the original script and the fixed one in [gist 3636007](https://gist.github.com/3636007) so other people can play with.

Final script is below:

```xml
<project default="main">
    <target name="main">
        <script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[
        task = project.createTask( 'macro' );

        if( task.getOwningTarget() == null ) {
            task.log( "Assigning an owner ..." );
            task.setOwningTarget( self.getOwningTarget() );
            task.log( "Task:  " + task.getOwningTarget() );
        }

        try {
            task.execute();
        } catch(err) {
            task.log( "Execution error: " + err.message );
        }

        ]]></script>
    </target>

    <macrodef name="macro">
        <sequential>
            <antcall target="antcall" />
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <target name="antcall">
        <echo>[antcall] succeed</echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

The resulting execution is:

```
$ ant
Buildfile: /Users/amusso/ant/bug/build.xml

main:
    [macro] Assigning an owner ...
    [macro] Task:  main

antcall:
     [echo] [antcall] succeed

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

\O/

Comment: I have opened https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53831 in ant issue tracker.